# OpenCV with OpenNi

Tags: opencv, kinect, openni

I have studied NITE 2.While looking for various examples i came across a few videos where OpenCV was used along with OpenNi. 
THe question is **for what exactly can opencv be used with OpenNI**. I understand this is very vague question yet i really need to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenCV is best of breed library for developing computer vision algorithms. It has great number of optimized algorithms that can be used for analysis of depth maps as well as RGB images that you can capture using OpenNI.

NITE is closed source library that contains set of very well implemented, but limited algorithms.

So if you want to implement something more than gives you NITE, you will need handy tool set for that. In general OpenCV is the best choice.

For instance you can use OpenCV + OpenNI to develop:

- Gender, Age or Emotion recognition using fusion of 3D and 2D data;
- 3D face recognition;
- custom gesture recognition;
- body shape measuring.

and many other tasks, which number is limited just by imagination.

> Depth sensors compatible with OpenNI (Kinect, XtionPRO, ...) are supported through VideoCapture class. Depth map, RGB image and some other formats of output can be retrieved by using familiar interface of VideoCapture (See [Using Kinect and other OpenNI compatible depth sensors](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/user_guide/ug_highgui.html?highlight=kinect))

Comment: Thank you so much Alexander for the reply.I think i do ve a good perspective about it all now.went through the link above and also read that there are various modules as part of opencv.I understand that we can capture the depth image using the VideoCapture class.can i ask you  which modules/classes can be used for placing 3D objects in the depth images so captured.in addition to that how can be simple collision detection,et al be implemented using the same?

Comment: videos i came across http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IubzysmmAYQ  and http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qOF5a039kTw n

Comment: OpenCV has no module for rendering 3D objects into 3D scene. You could take a look on other libraries ( e.g. [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/))

Comment: Oh thank you again ALexander.But i wonder what have they done in the videolink i ve shared above? :( cos its said he (the person in video) has used opencv.I wonder what has he used for those axes and the skeleton.

Comment: Description of  video [Kinect - Skeleton joints orientations](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IubzysmmAYQ) says, that "The axes are drawn using OpenCV" I can't see any other tasks for which OpenCV could be used here. It is simple demo. I guess that second demo uses OpenCV for the same purposes - just drawing results.